# Align element with multiline text to the center of parent block preserving left text-alignment

Tags: html, css

There is a menu with multiple items. Each item had one-line contents, aligned to the center of it. But suddenly one item with two-line contents has been added.

According to design plans this two-line item-contents-element still should be aligned to the center of parent item, but text in this item-contents-element should be left-aligned:
[how-it-should-look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PI9Pm.png)

Also, items are responsive, and items contents may change for this and other items - so just using fixed width for item contents is inappropriate.

Starting with [this code](https://jsfiddle.net/bs_4xxi/z0p4z9a4/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Align element wit multiline text to the center of parent block preserving left text-alignment</title>
        <style>
            .list-item {
              border: 1px solid #999;
              padding: 10px;
              text-align: center;
              width: 350px;
            }

            .item-contents {
              border: 1px dashed #999;
              display: inline-block;
              text-align: left;
              font-size: 30px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="list-item">
            <div class="item-contents">We've got a verylongwordhere</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

we've found [this solution](https://jsfiddle.net/bs_4xxi/z0p4z9a4/4/). But it doesn't work in IE11.
By the way, I'd be grateful if you'll explain to me how it works.

The question is: "**Is there any cross-browser (IE11, Chrome, FF, Safari) solution to implement this without JS?**"

EDIT: thank you all for your answers, but we cannot set fixed width for two reasons (sorry guys, that's my fault that I didn't included this in the question initially):

1. This is not universal enough (because item content text may change)
2. Item size are responsive so fixed item contents width will look good at one screen width, but bad at another screen width.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating HTML and CSS

```css
   .list-item {
          border: 1px solid #999;
          padding: 10px;
          text-align: center;
          width: 350px;
        }


.item-contents {
      border: 1px dashed #999;
      text-align: left;
      font-size: 30px;
      padding:10px
}
  
span.someClass {
    border:1px dashed #000;
    padding:5px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:left;
    max-width:60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-item">
    <span class="someClass">
      We've got a pretty much verylongwordhere
    </span>
 </div>
```